# Usage of prepositions is very difficult to choose

Tags: prepositions

I want to explain my results. So I use a figure to explain an erroneous result. Here my idea is to tell, because of missing of a specific segment (say segment 8), I got the wrong result. Assume, I have shown p1, p2 and segment 8 in the figure. And I have written it as;

> For example, in Fig. 15 **the** corner p1 is incorrectly fixed **to the** corner
>   p2 due to missing segment 8.

I have some doubts of the usage of correct prepositions, If I specifically referring to the figure, then can I use **THE** as I used in above sentence?

*However, I think I should use **as** instead of **to** and also **of** in front of segment.*

> For example, in Fig. 15 ***the*** corner p1 is incorrectly fixed ***as
>   the*** corner p2 due to missing ***of*** segment 8.

So, please give your comments on this. thanks

Comment: What is wrong is not just the prepositions: "... due to ***the*** missing segment 8". And in a technical paper, I would use a different verb than "fixed" here: "fixed to" → "connected to" or "fixed as" → "identified with".

Comment: @Peter Shor: thanks for the comments. what about this part ...the corner p1 is incorrectly fixed as the corner p2 ...

Comment: The problem is that "fixed to" and "fixed as" are both reasonably grammatical here, but mean different things, and I don't know which one you want to say.

Comment: @Peter: I'd say the "fixed as" usage is effectively *figurative* (some "real-world" phenomenon is effectively being *tied to* some particular word/classification).

Comment: @PeterShor is right.  To expound a bit, to say that *corner p1 is fixed as corner p2* means that corner p1 and p2 are the same corner, but saying *corner p1 is fixed to [the] corner p2* means that p1 is attached or connected to p2 permanently.

Comment: @gnp please let me know if I have answered your question. I will delete it, if it is not what you wanted.

Comment: “missing” isn't really used the way you have it here. You're first example is better in this regard (though there's no verb associated with "missing" and it sounds like a verb but it's not). I think you might be better off with “[...]due to **the lack of** segment 8.” I don't know what “fixed as” would mean at all.

Comment: To me, it seems better in its original form. Can you explain _why_ you think it should be “fixed as”?

Answer (score 1):

> For example, in Fig. 15 the corner p1 is incorrectly fixed to the
>   corner p2 due to missing segment 8.

I think that could use a few extra prepositions. Unless the **entire** name of these pieces are *corner p1* and *corner p2* you need *of* between them. In that case, it signals that they belong to or are a part of *p1* and *p2*.

Are you trying to say this?:

> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner **of** p1 is incorrectly *attached*
>   to the corner **of** p2 due to **the** missing segment 8.

If so, then you definitely **need** *of* in the above locations. You also need **the** before *missing* unless you revise it. As for the verb, *fixed **to*** is fine. It's a phrasal verb though, meaning that the preposition *to* following *fixed* is not optional; it's a verb phrase that changes the meaning slightly.

With the verb phrase *fixed **as***, it means set in place. I realize that doesn't sound much different, but *fixed as* means that it's more **permanent**

It might be better to choose a different verb altogether for clarity. *Attached* or *fastened* would be more concise, but that's optional. *Fixed to* is synonymous with those verbs.

> I have some doubts of the usage of correct prepositions, If I
>   specifically referring to the figure, then can I use THE as I used in
>   above sentence?

Yes, you can use *the*; however, *the* is a definite article, not a preposition,

> However, I think I should use as instead of to and also of in front of
>   segment.
>
> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner [of] p1 is incorrectly fixed
>   <del>as</del> **to** the corner [of] p2 due to **the** missing
>   <del>of</del> segment 8.

No, as I said above, you cannot use *fixed **as*** here. Depending on what you're trying to articulate, you might be able to add *of* before *segment 8*, but you cannot do that as written. And I think it's more concise without it.

For example, these are much more clear:

> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner [of] p1 is incorrectly fixed to the
>   corner [of] p2, **as** segment 8 **is missing.**
>
> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner [of] p1 is incorrectly fastened the
>   corner [of] p2, due to segment 8 **being missing**. (awkward)
>
> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner [of] p1 is incorrectly attached to
>   the corner [of] p2 **because** segment 8 **was not properly attached
>   first/beforehand**.

*Due to*, *as*, and *because* are all synonymous in the context above.

To give you a couple of examples using *of* before *segment 8*, it would look more like this:

> For example, in Fig. 15, the [of] corner p1 is incorrectly fixed to the
>   corner [of] p2, due to **the absence of** segment.
>
> For example, in Fig. 15, the corner [of] p1 is incorrectly fixed to the
>   corner [of] p2, due to **the missing portion of** segment 8.

Comment: +1 I wonder, however, if OP may not be using *fixed as* in the sense "firmly identified as" - as, for instance, it is used [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=SmUKVo0nC50C&pg=PA149&dq=%22is+fixed+as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ouqsUuuvJ4OcyQG674CIAQ&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22is%20fixed%20as%22&f=false). This, like the user's other questions, appears to deal with mathematically identifying entities on  photographs.

Comment: @StoneyB That's a great point. So while I've interpreted *fixed to* as meaning something akin to number two [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/fix%5B1%5D), if I understand you correctly, you think that it just as well could be numbers 3 or 4 (i.e. the only thing obvious is that the verb is transitive) And honestly, I don't think that understanding the precise nature of the action itself is 100% necessary to nail down the syntax. By and large, I think that [*numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fix) are **all** used with the same basic syntax.